# Vue Router how to substitute data from input to url

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tell us how you can implement such functionality.

After registration the user should specify his id in the input field, which will be his link. For example:

Step one: The registration form 
Step two: The form where the user specifies his id `domaine.com/id`

After that, the user gets to the `/profile` page, where he can edit his name and surname, for example.

How, and by what means, do I output data from the `/profile` page to a separate page with `/id`, which the user has specified after registration?

You were told that you can do it with the vue router, but how can you do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you use vue router, you can add some routes, for example :

```
        {
            name: "doc-create",
            path: "backend/docs/create",
            component: () => import("@/views/backend/doc/Create.vue"),
        },
        {
            name: "doc-view",
            path: "backend/docs/:id",
            component: () => import("@/views/backend/doc/View.vue"),
        },
```

/doc/:id means id is a parameter
Then in your vue file, in script you can retrieve id with : $route.params.id